# Is there an example of a Ricci flat algebraic surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Given a surface defined by a polynomial $f(x,y,z,...)=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

are there any known to be Ricci-flat but not flat? I am trying to find a simple example with smallest possible polynomial.

e.g. $x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0$ is not Ricci-flat as it is a sphere.
$(x^2+y^2-1)^2+(z^2+w^2-1)^2=0$ is Ricci flat but is also just flat because it is a flat torus.

I imagine some Euclidean form of a Schwarzschield wormhole type surface would work? Embedded in $\mathbb{R}^5$

(All I can find is surfaces defined in $\mathbb{CP}^n$ instead of Euclidean space. (I don't know how to convert these to surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^m$.)

I think the smallest example should be a 4-manifold thus defined by an equation $f(x,y,z,w,u)=0$. (Since for 3-manifolds the Riemann tensor can be decomposed into the Ricci tensor).

(2) Are there any polynomials shown to have zero-scalar curvature but non-zero Ricci-curvature?  I think the simplest example should be a 3-manifold defined by an equation $f(x,y,z,w)=0$ (Since for 2-manifolds the Ricci tensor is proportional to the Scalar tensor).